# UWP DataGrid set focus into cell

Tags: uwp, datagrid

I would like to set cursor and begin edit into element of cell.
In WPF it is easy

```
dataGrid1.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(
    dataGrid1.Items[0], dataGrid1.Columns[3]);
dataGrid1.BeginEdit();
```

How can I do same in UWP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In uwp, first you can set the SelectedIndex and CurrentColumn to achieve which cell you want to set focus, then using BeginEdit method to enter editing mode. In addition, you need to subscribe the PreparingCellForEdit event of DataGrid to to ensure the focus of the cell transfers to the focus of the TextBox inside. For example:

.xaml:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" PreparingCellForEdit="dataGrid1_PreparingCellForEdit">
......
</controls:DataGrid>
```

.cs:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGrid1.SelectedIndex = 0;
    dataGrid1.CurrentColumn = dataGrid1.Columns[3];
    dataGrid1.BeginEdit();
}

private void dataGrid1_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.EditingElement is TextBox textbox)
    {
        textbox.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
    }
}
```